# How to render a .phtml file through apache

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I want to render a .phtml file through Apache, however when I try, it renders the page as text and not as html.

In my vhost configuration, if I try to render an index.php, it executes properly. But when I change the DirectoryIndex to index.phtml and try to render the index.phtml present in the public directory it just renders text.

The vhost Config is:
    `code` 
    ServerName parminder.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/workspace/parminder_local_net/public"
    ErrorLog logs/parmindercom.log
    
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    
    DirectoryIndex index.phtml
*

What else do I need to configure for this to work? Do I need to use .htaccess? 
What is the basic concept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure Apache so it knows that you want .phtml files to be treated as PHP. See step 8 of [the PHP install guide](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php).

```
<FilesMatch "\.ph(p[2-6]?|tml)$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

... but .phtml is the file extension used for PHP 2. You should probably audit them, bring them up to modern PHP coding practises and rename them to follow current conventions.

Comment: Thank you, It worked by setting the above directives in my .htaccess file. Also, in httpd.conf I have: `code`AddType application/x-httpd-php .php

Comment: What did you write in .htaccess file ?

Comment: I saw a similar answer by you on a different question on `.phtml` extensions and asked my colleague about it. Apparently the views in Zend Framework went for this extension, and it's in their docs too.

Answer (score 3):

htaccess file
root folder --> folders -->html pages & subfolders

Try adding this to it:

`AddHandler php-script .php .php5 .php4 .php3 .html .htm .phtm`l

Comment: It should be "AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php .php5 .php4 .php3 .html .htm .phtml". The handler is not php-script.

Answer (score 1):

After installing the apache server, you need to mention which all files will be read by the apache parser,

which is done by mentioning the types of files.
like

**

```
> <FilesMatch \.php$>
>     SetHandler application/x-httpd-php </FilesMatch>
```

**

and in order to allow .php, .php2, .php3, .php4, .php5, .php6, and .phtml files to be executed as PHP, use below one

```
<FilesMatch "\.ph(p[2-6]?|tml)$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```