# Is it possible to use 'use as' for namespaces in a .phtml file?

Tags: html, namespaces, php

In a .phtml file, is it okay to do the following?

`<?php use App\Library as Lib; ?>
 <h3><?php Lib::getTitle(); ?></h3>....`

I have a .phtml file that uses a Utility class to make dropdowns and whatnot, didn't want to have to type out the whole namespace for everything.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: If you've configured your server like so, using `.phtml` file should be strictly identical as using `.php` files.

Comment: That's what I figured, but I wanted to make sure. Thanks, @D4V1D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've configured your server like so, using `.phtml` file should be strictly identical as using `.php` files.

[See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10355805/how-to-render-a-phtml-file-through-apache) (if you're running Apache).